# Rest API Consumption in flutter

Tags: rest, flutter, dart

**Problem**

I'm trying to receive data from a rest API in my flutter app, inside a future function but i keep getting the following error:
*type 'CastList<dynamic, List>' is not a subtype of type 'List'*.

The function I'm using to fetch the data is as follows:

```
static Future<List<Questionnaire>> fetchQuestionnaires() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:4010/phone/questionnaires');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        List<Questionnaire> resp =
            json.decode(response.body).cast<List<Questionnaire>>();

        List<Questionnaire> questionnaires = resp
            .map<Questionnaire>((dynamic item) => Questionnaire.fromJson(item))
            .toList();

        log(
          questionnaires.toString(),
        );

        return questionnaires;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Unable to fetch questionnaires');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      log(error.toString());
    }
  }
```

I don't understand why this is. Why does using cast, cast to *CastList<dynamic, Type>* and not the original Type? What changes do I do to get my data?

The data model is given below.

**Data Model**

The Data i expect from my backend is like this. An array called *questionnaires*, containing multiples of a *questionnaire*, each containing an *id* and a *displayQuestion*. A displayQuestion in turn has the *question text* and the *answers* Array_.

For this, I have the following structure in my Json.

```
[
    {
        "questionId": 1,
        "displayQuestions": [
            {
                "question": "how old are you",
                "answers": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my questionnaires.dart model

```
class Questionnaires {
  List<Questionnaire> _questionnaires;
  Questionnaires.fromJson(this._questionnaires);
}
```

This is questionnaire.dart model

```
class Questionnaire {
  int questionnaireId;
  List<DisplayQuestion> displayQuestions = [];
  Questionnaire(this.questionnaireId, this.displayQuestions);
  Questionnaire.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : questionnaireId = json['questionnaireId'],
        displayQuestions = json['displayQuestions'];
}
```

The code from display-question.dart model

```
class DisplayQuestion {
  String _question;
  List<String> _answers;
  String get question => this._question;

  List get answers => this._answers;

  DisplayQuestion(this._question, [List<String> answers])
      : this._answers = answers ?? [];

  DisplayQuestion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : _question = json['question'],
        _answers = json['answers'];
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the list at that point? What purpose do you think it serves?

Comment: because if i do, i get this error: 
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Questionnaire>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does using cast, cast to CastList<dynamic, Type> and not the original Type?

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html), `myList.cast<MyType>` returns a `List<MyType>`. In your case you're calling `resp.cast<List<Questionnaire>>`, so the return will be `List<List<Questionnaire>>`, which is not what you want.

If you're asking about `CastList<dynamic, Type>`, it's a subclass of `List<Type>`, see the [source code](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/d63d5d93a59b370bf5f5c277109110cb67a96b75/sdk/lib/internal/cast.dart#L172). It's useful because `CastList` doesn't need to create a new list, it's just a wrapper around the original list where each element is cast with `as Type` before being returned.

> What changes do I do to get my data?

The problem is you're calling `resp.cast<Type>` where `resp` is not a list that constains `Type`.

Here's a working sample based on the code you provided:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final sampleJson = """[
    {
        "questionId": 1,
        "displayQuestions": [
            {
                "question": "how old are you",
                "answers": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
""";

class DisplayQuestion {
  String question;
  List<String> answers;
  DisplayQuestion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : question = json["question"],
        answers = json["answers"].cast<String>();

  String toString() => 'question: $question | answers: $answers';
}

class Questionnaire {
  int questionnaireId;
  List<DisplayQuestion> displayQuestions;
  Questionnaire.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : questionnaireId = json['questionnaireId'],
        displayQuestions = (json['displayQuestions'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((questionJson) => DisplayQuestion.fromJson(questionJson))
            .toList();

  String toString() => '$displayQuestions';
}

List<Questionnaire> parseQuestionnaires() {
  List<Questionnaire> questionnaires =
      (json.decode(sampleJson) as List<dynamic>)
          .map((questionnaireJson) => Questionnaire.fromJson(questionnaireJson))
          .toList();
  return questionnaires;
}

void main() {
  print(parseQuestionnaires());
  // => [[question: how old are you | answers: [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. 
How do i although get display Question in a from where string is an attribute on its own, and answers is a list with each element being a string?
right now the question is displayed, and then the answers after a '|'. this is not how my widget that displays everything expects the data to be

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you post that in a new SO question showing what you tried, what you got, and what you want? If you paste the link to it here I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for reaching back. I was able to solve the problem. Tried around for a bit and put the override of the toString function in the correct format.